# How to separate two different sliders with breakpoints in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement two different sliders with swiper.js.
Above 768px and below.
But I can't successfully reset and regenerate.
Based on the screen width of 768px, I would like the two sliders to switch seamlessly.
I would appreciate it if you could teach me.

Here is the actual js code.

```
// ***** Swiper@8.4.5 *****
'use strict';

let destroyed = true;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

   if (destroyed == false) {    
      this.mySwiper.destroy(false, true);
      destroyed = true;
   }

    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');

    const checkBreakpoint = (e) => {

        if (e.matches) {
            const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-main', {

                init: true,

                loop: true,

                spaceBetween: 20,

                speed: 300,

                thresholdDelta: 100,

                allowTouchMove: true,

                centeredSlides: true,

                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    clickable: true,
                    type: 'bullets'
                },
            });
          destroyed = false;
        }
        else {
            const thumb = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-media');

            const switchThumb = (index) => {
                document.querySelector('.thumb-media-active').classList.remove('thumb-media-active');
                thumb[index].classList.add('thumb-media-active');
            };

            const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-main', {

                init: true,

                loop: false,

                spaceBetween: 20,

                speed: 800,

                allowTouchMove: false,

                centeredSlides: true,

                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                },

                on: {
                    afterInit: (swiper) => {
                        thumb[swiper.realIndex].classList.add('thumb-media-active');
                        for (let i = 0; i < thumb.length; i++) {
                            thumb[i].onclick = () => {
                                swiper.slideTo(i);
                            };
                        }
                    },

                    slideChange: (swiper) => {
                        switchThumb(swiper.realIndex);
                    },
                },
            });
          destroyed = false;
        };
    }
    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", checkBreakpoint);
    checkBreakpoint(mediaQuery);
})
```

swiper.js destroy doesn't work.

Comment: Your Q not clear. What do you mean "to switch". Swiper already support breakpoints - https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints - no need for all of this code.

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation is not enough.

Two types of sliders are prepared with a screen width of 768px as a breakpoint.
One works with navigation, the other works with pagination and swipe.

The problem is that the pagination doesn't work with the swipe when the breakpoint is passed, or the navigation stops in the middle of the slider.

So, I want to destroy the instance once and regenerate it, but it doesn't work.

It seems that complicated settings cannot be made with the breakpoints provided by the official API.

Comment: As a side note, reloading works fine.
However, a problem arises when screen widths move seamlessly.
(I don't want to reload if possible.)

Comment: Was self resolved.
Instead of using one slider, I created two sliders.
Also, if I set an if statement at each breakpoint and destroy the instance, it worked fine.
Thank you for your advice.